# How can I show this sequence $u_n$ is divergent: $u_n=\exp( n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

How can I show this sequence $u_n$ is divergent:

$$u_n=\exp( n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon))\quad n\in \mathbb{N}^*;\quad \epsilon \in (0,1)$$

My attempts:

\begin{align*}
u_n&=\exp( n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon))\\
u_n&=\exp( n(\log n-\log(n+\epsilon))-\epsilon \log(n+\epsilon))\\
u_n&=-\exp( n(-\log n+\log(n+\epsilon))+\epsilon \log(n+\epsilon))\\
&\leq -\epsilon \log(n+\epsilon)\\
\end{align*}
note that
$-\epsilon \log(n+\epsilon)\to -\infty$
but i'm stuck here

**Edit**

$$u_n =e^{n\log(n)-(n+e)\log(n + e)}$$

$$\log(n+t)=\log(n(\frac{t}{n}+1))=\log(n) + \frac{t}{n} +o(\frac{t}{n})$$
can we say that
$$n\log(n+t)=n\log(n) + t +o(t)$$
then
$$u_n=e^{nlog(n)-(n+t)log(n+t)}=e^{n\log(n)-n\log(n+t)-t\log(n+t)}\sim ?$$

Answer (score 2):

When $n>1$, both $(n+\epsilon)$ and $\log(n+\epsilon)$ are positive increasing functions in $\epsilon$, i.e.

$(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon)>n\log n$

and hence

$n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon)<0.$

Taking $\exp$ of something negative results in something smaller than $1$, and so the expression doesn't diverge after all.

---

In more details, let's first write

${\mathrm e}^{n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon)}=\dfrac{1}{{\mathrm e}^{n\log(n+\epsilon)+\epsilon\log(n+\epsilon)-n\log n}}=\dfrac{1}{{\mathrm e}^{n\log(n+\epsilon)-n\log n}}\dfrac{1}{(n+\epsilon)^\epsilon}.$

In ${\mathrm e}^{n\log(n+\epsilon)-n\log n}$, we can get rid of $n\log(n)$ by observing that

$n\log(n+\epsilon)$

$=n\log(\frac{n+\epsilon}{n}\cdot n)$

$=n \log(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n})+n\log(n)$

$=\log(\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^n)+n\log(n)$

and so the expression becomes

$\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^n}\dfrac{1}{(n+\epsilon)^\epsilon}.$

The limit of $\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^n$ is the constant ${\mathrm e}^\epsilon$ but $(n+\epsilon)^\epsilon$ blows up and hence the expression becomes $0$.

Comment: ur spirt is to show that $u_n={\mathrm e}^{n\log n-(n+\epsilon)\log(n+\epsilon)}={+ \infty}$ then $u_n$ is divergent

Comment: @Educ: I don't know what you mean. I show that $u_n$ is not divergent.

Comment: i thought it's $u_n$ is divergent as @anorton show also

Comment: @Educ: He has several errors.

Comment: could you point it to me, for example is that true $e^{\alpha \log(x+\beta)}\sim x+\beta \sim x$

Comment: ${\mathrm e}^{\alpha\log(x+\beta)}={\mathrm e}^{\log((x+\beta)^\alpha)}=(x+\beta)^\alpha=(x+\beta)\cdot(x+\beta)^{\alpha-1}$. Clearly, for $\alpha\neq 1$, this does not got as $(x+\beta)$. But besides the wrong heuristics, he also has simpler sign errors.

Comment: @NikolajK Ah... I see where I went wrong.  Please ignore my answer. :)

Comment: @NikolajK could you please tell me if i have 
$$\log(n+t)=\log(n(\frac{t}{n}+1))=\log(n) + \frac{t}{n} +o(\frac{t}{n})$$
can we say that  
$$n\log(n+t)=n\log(n) + t +o(t)$$  am i right

Comment: $\log(n+t)=\log(n\,(1+\frac{t}{n}))=\log(n)+\log(1+\frac{t}{n})=\log(n)+{\frac{t}{n}}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\left(-\frac{t}{n}\right)^k$ is the exact relation, and that's also $\log(n)+{\frac{t}{n}}+{\mathcal O}(\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^3)$. You know you don't have to ask me, just let WorframAlpha do the series expansion. Type in "Series[Log[1+x],{x,0,3}]" for this case, i.e. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series[Log[1%2Bx]%2C{x%2C0%2C3}]

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
(n+\varepsilon)\log (n+\varepsilon)=&(n+\varepsilon)\log\left(n\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)\right)\\
=&(n+\varepsilon)\log n+(n+\varepsilon)\log\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)\\
=&(n+\varepsilon)\log n+\underbrace{\frac{(n+\varepsilon)}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^n}_{=:A_{\varepsilon}(n)}
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{align*}
n\log n-(n+\varepsilon)\log (n+\varepsilon)
=&n\log n-(n+\varepsilon)\log n-A_{\varepsilon}(n)\\
=&-\varepsilon\log n-A_{\varepsilon}(n)\\
=&\log n^{-\varepsilon}-A_{\varepsilon}(n)
\end{align*}

Thus
\begin{align*}
u_n
=&\exp\left({\log n^{-\varepsilon}-A_{\varepsilon}(n)}\right)\\
=&\exp(\log n^{-\varepsilon})\exp(-A_{\varepsilon}(n))\\
=&\frac1{n^{\varepsilon}e^{A_{\varepsilon}(x)}}
\end{align*}

Ok: now
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}A_{\varepsilon}(n)=\varepsilon
$$
and this holds for all $\varepsilon>0$ fixed.

Moreover $n^{\varepsilon}$ goes to infinity, for every $\varepsilon>0$ fixed.

Thus $u_n\to 0$ as $n$ approaches to $+\infty$.

Comment: i think you have typo in ur  last ligne, you should write  : Thus $u_n\to 0$  as $n$ approaches to $+\infty $

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
e^{(n+\varepsilon)\log(n+\varepsilon)}=(n+\varepsilon)^{n+\varepsilon}=n^{n+\varepsilon}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{\varepsilon},
$$
so
$$
e^{n\log n - (n+\varepsilon)\log(n+\varepsilon)}=\frac{n^n}{n^{n+\varepsilon}}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{-n}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{-\varepsilon}=n^{-\varepsilon}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{-n}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{-\varepsilon}.
$$
The middle term converges to $e^{-\varepsilon}$ and the right-hand term converges to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  So altogether you have
$$
e^{n\log n - (n+\varepsilon)\log(n+\varepsilon)} \sim (e n)^{-\varepsilon}\rightarrow 0,
$$
using the fact that $\varepsilon > 0$ only in the final step.

Comment: i can't see how did you get this $$(n+\varepsilon)^{n+\varepsilon}=n^{n+\varepsilon}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)$$

Comment: @Educ: The relation is wrong, he missed an exponent of $\epsilon$ at the end. The general computation being performed is $(a+b)^{c+d}=a^{c+d}(1+b/a)^{c+d}=a^{c+d}(1+b/a)^c(1+b/a)^d$.