# Find the value of $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Determine if the following limits exist
>
> $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor$$

note that $$\frac{1}{x}-1 <\lfloor  \frac{1}{x}\rfloor  \leq \frac{1}{x}$$
$$1-x <x\lfloor  \frac{1}{x}\rfloor  \leq 1$$

i'm stuck here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that $\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor=0$ for $x>1$, hence $x\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor$ is identically zero on $]1,+\infty[$. Hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: could you see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102819/u-n-exp-n-log-n-n-epsilon-logn-epsilo

Comment: @Educ: answered, tell me what do you think